# Why does Mysql decide to use an index on column specified in Order By clause when its not present in where clause?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Why does Mysql decide to use an index on column specified in Order By clause although that column is not present in where clause ? 
This happens when Order By + Limit clause are used together in the query.

Example query:

```
select col1, col2,col3 from table_name where col1 = 'x' and col3='y' order by colY limit 3;
```

table_name has 9M records

In the absence of limit clause, 
   mysql uses the index on col1 column which is wayy faster.

Comment: Is it causing you a problem?

Comment: This needs an index on `col1,col3,colY` for the index to work on that query.

Comment: Are col1 and/or col3 indexed? _Also, `,` is not a logical operator._

Comment: it has an index on col1. when i remove the limit clause, it decides to use the col1 index and the query seems to be10x fast.

Comment: @Uueerdo , was a typo. i have edited the question. And yes col1 has an index on it

Answer (score 1):

**Better**

```
select  col1, col2,col3
    from  table_name
    where  col1 = 'x'
      and  col3 = 'y'
    order by  col4
    limit  3;
```

The optimal index is one of these two:

```
INDEX(col1, col3, col4)
INDEX(col3, col1, col4)
```

In both, the Optimizer can completely resolve the `WHERE` and do the `ORDER BY` and even stop after 3 rows due to the `LIMIT`.

**Best.** Even better performance would come from adding `col2` to the *end* of either.  This makes it a "covering" index, so all the work can be done in the index's BTree without touching the data's BTree.

**Back to your question**

If you don't have one of those indexes, the Optimizer is in a quandary, and often picks the wrong of the two likely choices.  Let's say you have only

```
INDEX(col1), INDEX(col4)
```

Plan A focuses on filtering:  Use `col1`, but have to sort all the matching rows before peeling off 3.  But it might get a million rows and have to sort them.

Plan B avoids sorting:  Scan through the index in `col4` order.  If it is really lucky, the first 3 rows will match the `WHERE` clause.  If it is really unlucky, it will scan the entire table without finding 3 acceptable rows.  But they will be sorted!

The "statistics" are meager, and cannot realistically decide between the two choices.

Either Plan could be really slow.

Similar problems occur with `JOINs` with the `WHERE` clause filtering on both tables.